# Date field not updating with .updateMany() - mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm updating the password for my app. The password hashes and updates fine. I get nModified: 1. I log out and can log in with new password, but the date field never updates? How can I get that field to update too?

```
router.put("/password/:id", (req, res) => {
  let user = req.body;
  let retrievedOldPassword = user.retrievedOldPassword.password;
  let result;
  let newPasswordHash;

  bcrypt.compare(req.body.oldPassword, retrievedOldPassword, function(
    err,
    res
  ) {
    if (err) {
      return err;
    }
    result = res;
    console.log(res);
  });

  if (result) {
  } else {
    bcrypt.hash(req.body.newPassword, 10, function(err, hash) {
      newPasswordHash = hash;
      // res.sendStatus(401);

      User.updateMany(
        { password: retrievedOldPassword },
        { password: newPasswordHash },
        { passwordCreated: Date.now() }
      )
        .then(user => {
          console.log(user);
          res.json(user);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter of `updateMany()` is for options. You need to put `passwordCreated: Date.now()` in the second parameter then it will be updated:

```
User.updateMany(
    { password: retrievedOldPassword },
    { password: newPasswordHash, passwordCreated: Date.now() },
  )
```

More info: [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#syntax)